# How do I write an awk program that matches #ifdef...#else...#endif C pre-processor macros?

Tags: c, awk, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I have a large corpus of C programs that have the following code blocks.

```
100. #ifdef DEBUG1
    .
    .
    .
102. #else    
    .
    .
    .
105. #endif
```

or,

```
200. #ifdef DEBUG2
    .
    .
    .
206. #endif
```

Moreover, a single file may contain multiple `#DEBUG` macros. I want to extract the line numbers corresponding to the macros. Assuming the numbers in the code snippet are the line numbers in the source file, I want the output to be in the following format:

```
FILE - MACRO_NAME - IFDEF - ELIF - ENDIF
----------------------------------------
prog.c - DEBUG1   -  100  -  102  -  105
prog.c - DEBUG2   -  200  -   X   -  206
```

How can I write an `awk` program to achieve the same? If `awk` is not the appropriate tool, what tool can I use?

Comment: How robust does it need to be? For example will it need to be able to ignore `#ELIF` statements inside strings and comments? How about nested definitions like `#ifdef DEBUG1 ... #ifdef DEBUG2 ... #endif ... #endif`?

Comment: It doesn't need to be that robust. I know the dataset well. There's no such occurrences, and even if it's there, it'd be extremely rare.

Comment: OK then [edit] your question to include at least 1 example of a concise, testable sample input file and the associated expected output so we have something to test a potential solution against so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Awk actually *has* associative arrays so the approach I would take would be:

1. For each `#ifdef` (or equivalent such as `#if 1`), increment a variable then use that to store the `if` line number, setting the `else` and `endif` line numbers to -1.
2. For an `#else` line, use the current variable to set  the `else` line number.
3. For an `#endif`, output whatever details you have for the line numbers then decrement the variable.
4. For an `#elif`, you need to combine `#else` and `#if` actions and ensure that the relevant `#end` closes off *all* the `#if/#elif` lines.

For example, here's a self-contained `bash` script showing how it could work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Use this script as input file as well, luckily C preprocessor
# macros look like bash comments.

#ifdef XYZZY
    # Some text inside the first ifdef
    #if 0
        # This is the inner bit.
    #endif
    #if 1
        # blah blah blah
    #elif defined TWISTY
        # yada yada yada
    #elif defined PASSAGES
        # run out of phrases
    #else
        # still got nothing
    #endif
#else
    #ifdef PLUGH
        # This is the plugh stuff
    #else
        # This is the anti-plugh stuff
    #endif
#endif

awk <$0 '
    $1 == "#ifdef" || $1 == "#if" {
        level++
        line_mac[level] = $0
        gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", line_mac[level])
        line_if[level] = NR
        line_else[level] = "X"
        line_end[level] = "X"
        typ_elif[level] = 0
        next
    }
    $1 == "#elif" {
        line_else[level] = NR
        level++
        line_mac[level] = $0
        gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", line_mac[level])
        line_if[level] = NR
        line_else[level] = "X"
        line_end[level] = "X"
        typ_elif[level] = 1
        next
    }
    $1 == "#else" {
        line_else[level] = NR
        next
    }
    $1 == "#endif" {
        while (typ_elif[level] == 1) {
            printf "if-line %-4s, else-line %-4s, endif-line %-4s, macro '%s'\n", line_if[level], line_else[level], NR, line_mac[level]
            level--
        }
        printf "if-line %-4s, else-line %-4s, endif-line %-4s, macro '%s'\n", line_if[level], line_else[level], NR, line_mac[level]
        level--
    }
    '
```

The output of that (with numbered lines from the file for checking) is:

```
 1: #!/usr/bin/env bash
 2: 
 3: # Use this script as input file as well, luckily C preprocessor
 4: # macros look like bash comments.
 5: 
 6: #ifdef XYZZY
 7:     # Some text inside the first ifdef
 8:     #if 0
 9:         # This is the inner bit.
10:     #endif
11:     #if 1
12:         # blah blah blah
13:     #elif defined TWISTY
14:         # yada yada yada
15:     #elif defined PASSAGES
16:         # run out of phrases
17:     #else
18:         # still got nothing
19:     #endif
20: #else
21:     #ifdef PLUGH
22:         # This is the plugh stuff
23:     #else
24:         # This is the anti-plugh stuff
25:     #endif
26: #endif

if-line 8   , else-line X   , endif-line 10  , macro #if 0
if-line 15  , else-line 17  , endif-line 19  , macro #elif defined PASSAGES
if-line 13  , else-line 15  , endif-line 19  , macro #elif defined TWISTY
if-line 11  , else-line 13  , endif-line 19  , macro #if 1
if-line 21  , else-line 23  , endif-line 25  , macro #ifdef PLUGH
if-line 6   , else-line 20  , endif-line 26  , macro #ifdef XYZZY
```

Answer (score 2):

Given [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603241/how-do-i-write-an-awk-program-that-matches-ifdef-else-endif-c-pre-process?noredirect=1#comment97905019_55603241) something like this should be all you need (using GNU awk for ENDFILE and ARGIND):

```
awk '
{ hit = 0 }
$1 == "#ifdef" {
    macroname = $2
    count[macroname]++
    hit = 1
}
$1 ~ /#(else|endif)$/ { hit = 1 }
hit { fnr[macroname,count[macroname],$1] = FNR; hit = 0 }
ENDFILE {
    if (ARGIND == 1) {
        print "FILE", "MACRO_NAME", "IFDEF", "ELIF", "ENDIF"
    }
    for (macroname in count) {
        for (i=1; i<=count[macroname]; i++) {
            print FILENAME, macroname, fnr[macroname,i,"#ifdef"]+0, fnr[macroname,i,"#elif"]+0, fnr[macroname,i,"#endif"]+0
        }
    }
    delete count
    delete fnr
}
' *.c
```

It's untested of course since you didn't provide an example we could test against. Set `OFS` or use `printf` or pipe to `column` to get differently formatted output if you care.

Comment: Ed, you can grab the first 26 lines of the script in my answer for testing, that should at least give you a level of confidence that it works.

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks but your example is covering cases that I asked about in a comment and [the OP said don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603241/how-do-i-write-an-awk-program-that-matches-ifdef-else-endif-c-pre-process/55605101?noredirect=1#comment97905019_55603241) in her data and so my script won't handle.

Comment: I was trying your script out to try understand it better (my awk foo is weak), but was getting slightly wrong results. It looked like it was probably something simple like an off-by-1 thing.

Comment: I'm curious, do you generally prefer the weird array indices concatenation over multi-dimensional arrays in awk? Is it much of a performance boost?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi I don't consider performance when choosing which array indexing to use, just portability and conciseness. `arr[x,y]` will work in any awk while `arr[x][y]` is gawk-only so I use the former unless there's a reason to use the latter such as it makes the code noticeably more concise.

Comment: thanks, I thought that might be the case but wasn't sure since you were using other gawk features.  I was just reading through the manual a bit today and was having trouble wrapping my head around that style

Comment: @jenesaisquoi I'd been using that style for literally about a quarter century before gawk came up with the other style so I've had some time to get used to it :-).

Comment: haha that's crazy, I guess its been around long enough to have spawned perl and then some

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @paxdiablo's answer. If you have `gawk` and are using multiple files as input, you could take advantage of the `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` rules to print the macros from each file.

Note, unlike the `BEGIN/END` blocks, which only run once at the beginning and end of all input, these are run at the beginning/end of each file (unsuprisingly).

So, a simplified script, ignoring `#else` etc., for which you could just add additional rules, an awk script like the following might be useful for multiple input files,

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    printf "%-10s | %-10s | %-5s | %-5s\n", "FILE", "MACRO", "IFDEF", "ENDIF";
    print "----------------------------------------"
}

BEGINFILE {
    delete macros;
    delete locs;
    i = 0;
}

/^[ \t]*#ifdef[\t ]+([^ \t])+/ {
    macros[i++] = $2;
    locs[i]["start"] = FNR;
}

/^[ \t]*#endif/ {
    locs[--i]["end"] = FNR;
}

ENDFILE {
    for (i = 0; i < length(macros); i++) {
        printf "%-10s - %-10s - %-4d - %-4d\n", 
            FILENAME, macros[i], locs[i]["start"], locs[i]["end"];
    }
}
```

---

Which should output something like the following,

```
$ ./defs.awk tst.h tst2.h 

FILE       | MACRO      | IFDEF | ENDIF
----------------------------------------
tst.h      - DEBUG1     - 0    - 5   
tst.h      - INNER1     - 1    - 4   
tst2.h     - DEBUG2     - 0    - 3
```